# Searching file contents without storing the file in db

Tags: database, filesystems, alfresco

I've been playing with [alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/) recently.  It's basically a document management system that seems to be pretty solid.  I did some searching to see how alfresco was managing their documents to see if they were storing the files in the db or via the file system.

After some digging around I found a pretty nice back and forth reply between some of the alfresco employees [stating that in fact the files are not stored in the db but stored on the filesystem](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/non-technical-alfresco-discussion/does-alfresco-store-documents-files-or-db-any-limits).

Here's what I don't seem to be understanding.  At the top of alfresco you can "Search" for a file.  I search by entering text that actually appears in the contents of the file, I am not searching by the file name.  For some reason, the search returns the right results...

Considering alfresco is only storing meta data in the database and not actual file content.  How does their search work such that it can search file contents?
I ask because I am currently working on a dms based system much like alfresco and it would be nice to understand if there is some sort of other process reading the file contents to index them into the search?

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using? The default way that search is done changed fairly recently is all

Comment: Basically though, the answers are [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) plus one of [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco stores the metadata in the database, and the file on the disk. However, with OOTB configuration it also indexes all of the metadata AND the file contents into the Lucene/SOLR subsystem.

Most of the searches later on are done against that index, even though the search against the database is possible.

Part of your Alfresco configuration is to decide which metadata to index, and whether to use FTS at all.

The documentation is not perfect, but you should be able to find a decent enough explanation of this. For example:

http://docs.alfresco.com/
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/admin-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

When you upload file to alfresco it invokes transformers in backend. Convert it to txt then extract text out of it. Index that content using search engine and hence you can search them based on content of file.
Hope it is clear to you now

You can control indexing behavior by changing values of **"cm:indexControl"** aspect

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/admin-indexes.html

Comment: Where is your reference for this sort of answer?